# How can I wrap words into span elements if they are not already wrapped?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As I wrote in the title - I'm looking for a way to wrap words into span elements. This should only be done if they not already wrapped. I've absolutely no idea how I can do this. I've tried it below but this works only for the first time. When I do it a second time, the old words getting wrapped x times also if they are already wrapped.

```js
function wrap() {
  jQuery("div").html(jQuery("div").html().replace(/Johnny/g, '<span class="wrapper" contenteditable="false">Johnny</span>'));
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny</div>
<button onclick="wrap()">Wrap Text</button>
```

So hopefully someone has an idea how I can fix the wrapping issue - maybe with a check?

Comment: Can you check the childNode count of the target element? If it's 0 wrap, if greater, don't.

Comment: Is this possible with a regex?

Comment: Try it. What is the use case? Will the wrapping only happen once? If you give the container div a class so that you can run a query on it, check it's child node counts, and then if it passes, do your wrapping.

Comment: Yes I need to do it multiple times. Thats the problem. So in this case the non-wrapped-words should get wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 function wrap() {
      $(".wrapper").contents().unwrap();
      $("div").html($("div").html().replace(/Johnny/g, '<span class="wrapper" contenteditable="false">Johnny</span>'));
    }
```

Comment: This way the word get's remove too inside the wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the regex :)

```js
function wrap() {
  jQuery("div")
  .html(
    jQuery("div")
      .html()
      .replace(/(?!<span>)Johnny(?!<\/span>)/g, '<span class="wrapper" contenteditable="false">Johnny</span>')
  );
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny, My name is Johnny</div>
<button onclick="wrap()">Wrap Text</button>
```